# Recover atime after vim

Tags: files, audit, forensics, atime

I've `vim`ed a file, and only afterwards realised that I need the `atime` (last access time) for the file. **Is there any way to recover the `atime` for a file after accessing it inadvertently?**

The filesystem is mounted as so:

```
UUID=XXXX /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

I'm interested in a distro-neutral solution, however barring that I am currently using Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Comment: I wouldn't count on it, but you never know. What filesystem & mount options do you have?

Comment: Doing a `cat file`  will not change the `atime` at all. You can check it using `stat file` If you used `view file` or `vi file` that would alter `Access, Modify and Change`  attributes

Comment: @val0x00ff: I added the fstab options to the question.

Comment: @dotancohen The access time cannot be recovered. The system doesn't keep track of file access times. This is for a reason since auditing otherwise would be impossible

Comment: @val0x00ff: Thanks, val. I figured that was the answer, but I had to hear it from someone with more experience than me. I'll leave the question open if some neckbeard guru ever comes across it with an answer out of Mordor.

Comment: @val0x00ff Unix filesystems do keep track of file access times (though this is disabled by default on modern Linux systems for performance reasons). What they hardly ever do is keep **logs** of access times, so that when the atime is updated, old values are not recorded anywhere. This is because the logs would be huge, not for any reason related to auditing (on the contrary, systems with pressing auditing requirements would log all atimes).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. **There is no history of previous `atime` values kept in memory by the system.**

Well, to be completely honest, the previous `atime` value may exist somewhere on RAM or even on disk, but you wouldn't know where, nor for how long.